# Mysql query for getting today's data in a sub-query #mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get today's data in MySQL query.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(score) AS tscore,
    (SELECT 
            players.id_company
        FROM
            players
        WHERE
            id = 377) AS id_company,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(players_score.score),
                DATE_FORMAT(players_score.reg_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
        FROM
            players_score
        WHERE
            id_player = 377
                AND DATE(reg_dt) = CURDATE())
FROM
    players_score
WHERE
    id_player = 377
```

In this query, it shows the error message that we can select one column which is understandable as I have used (col1, col2(for date)) as col. but I need a solution to get this done. thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very coherent. Could you show the exact error given? If you're pulling just today's date, why don't you simple select today's date instead of pulling it from the table?

Comment: a subselect can only return one value, never 2

Comment: Use 2 subselects, one for `SUM(players_score.score)` and other for `DATE_FORMAT(players_score.reg_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: @Asgar I can't use two subselects because what I need is SUM(players_score.score) in today's date. so this DATE_FORMAT() should be used within this select. actually I want to compare date (excluding) time because my reg_date is in DATETIME format, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need today's data only, You should use the condition at the last only -

```
SELECT 
    SUM(score) AS tscore,
    (SELECT 
            players.id_company
        FROM
            players
        WHERE
            id = PS.id_player) AS id_company,  -- I have changed the 377 to players_score to make the query more dynamic.
    SUM(players_score.score),
    DATE_FORMAT(players_score.reg_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM
    players_score PS
WHERE
    id_player = 377
AND DATE(reg_dt) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: I want to get today's data and I have reg_date in DATETIME format CURDATE() function won't work as I need to compare only date(excluding the time). thanks

Comment: yes it made it work using CURDATE() with DATE(reg_dt). just needed to put it in the right place. thanks (y)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your schema or data, so there could very well be more efficient ways of gathering this information, like the date seems like it should be set as the current date if that's what you're pulling, instead of referencing the table rows for the date, but the following should work for you in regards to pulling the sums from different tables in the same query.

The problem with your query was that there are multiple things being asked and tallied in a single query, which won't work.

```
SELECT 
    (select SUM(score) AS tscore FROM players_score WHERE id_player = 377 AND DATE(reg_dt) = CURDATE()),
    (SELECT players.id_company FROM players WHERE id = 377) AS id_company,
    (SELECT SUM(players_score.score WHERE id_player = 377 AND DATE(reg_dt) = CURDATE()),
    (select DATE_FORMAT(players_score.reg_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM players_score WHERE id_player = 377 AND DATE(reg_dt) = CURDATE())
```

Comment: the CURDATE() function won't work here as I need to compare the date excluding time from it to get today's data